# How do I remove the itunes published languaged set to english?

Tags: iphone, email, local

The app is for french and in french but when developed, I started with a shell with an english locale only and filled in the english locale with french translations...

I have 2 drawbacks from that:
1- it appears on itunes with language being "English"... which is confusing because the app is in French
2- when i use the "tell a friend" function, the default email buttons "send" and "cancel" are in english instead of being the french default ones... which again is not very good...

I tried adding a french local and got a new localised.string file... and tried to delete from xcode the english one but it is not allowed. I tried deleteing the files from the finder but I get them in red in xcode now and not sure what it means.

Does anyone what should I do please?

Thanks a lot

Cheers,
geebee

Comment: I still have the problem above - so if anyone has an idea, please let me know - thanks